# Чистый си, segmentation fault помогите пожалуйста

Tags: c, строки, память

```
#include <stdio.h> // библиотека для ввода/вывода
#include <string.h> // для функции разделения строки на подстроки
#include <ctype.h> // для проверки слова на то, что оно является числом
// определение количества чисел (не цифр) в строке. т.е: траляля 123 qwerty 14. // Ответ 2. 

int main()
{
    char *line; // строка
    const char *sep = ",.- "; // символы, по которым будем разделять ее на слова
    printf("Введите строку: ");
    fgets(line, 100, stdin);; // вводим строку
    printf("%s", line);
    int sum = 0;
    char *word = strtok (line, sep); // во втором параметре указаны разделители

    while (word != NULL) // пока есть лексемы
    {
        if (isdigit(word)) 
            sum++;
        word = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    }
    printf("Результат: %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотели сказать этим `isdigit(word)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
char *line;
```

В `line` - какой-то мусор, указывает в какое-то левое место в памяти.

И в это левое место вы читаете:

```
fgets(line, 100, stdin);
```

Понятно, что не работает...

Напишите хотя бы

```
char line[100];
```

Comment: Так результат всегда 0

Comment: @Алексей isdigit() принимает символ а не строку

Comment: Это уже второй вопрос. Я ответил на вопрос о segmentation fault.

Comment: @Not Bjarne Stroustrup а как тогда проверить лучше?

Comment: @Алексей: Поверить **что**?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить проверку на то, что слово состит **только** из цифр. Это и будет **число**. Если требуется в задании, то нужно анализировать наличие десятичной точки.

```
#include <stdio.h> // библиотека для ввода/вывода
#include <string.h> // для функции разделения строки на подстроки
#include <ctype.h> // для проверки слова на то, что оно является числом
// определение количества чисел (не цифр) в строке. т.е: траляля 123 qwerty 14. // Ответ 2. 

int main()
{
    char line[128]; // строка
    const char *sep = ",.- "; // символы, по которым будем разделять ее на слова
    int sum = 0;
    int j, len, flag;

    printf("Введите строку:\n");
    fgets(line, 127, stdin); // вводим строку

    char *word = strtok (line, sep); // во втором параметре указаны разделители

    while (word != NULL) // пока есть лексемы
    {
        // Токен содержит только цифры?
        flag = 0;
        len = strlen(word);
        for(j=0; j<len; j++) {
            if (! isdigit(word[j])) flag = -1; 
        }
        if (flag == 0) sum++;
        word = strtok (NULL, sep);
    }
    printf("Результат: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавляю *отдельный* ответ, так как он - на второй вопрос о том, как считать количество чисел.

Не сказано, *какие числа*, так что я подразумеваю - в том числе с плавающей точкой. Например, `1.23e-34`. А значит, точка и минус как разделители слов, использовать нельзя.

Далее, не указано, но подразумевается кодом - что числа считаются только если они - полные слова, например, 1234_5678 как два числа не рассматриваются.

Тогда вот мое решение:

```
int isNumber(const char * word)
{
    char * end;
    double d = strtod(word,&end);
    return *end == 0;
}

int main()
{
    const char *sep = "\n\t,;: "; // символы, по которым будем разделять ее на слова
    printf("Введите строку: ");
    char line[256];
    fgets(line, 256, stdin);; // вводим строку
    printf("%s", line);

    int sum = 0;
    for(char *word = strtok(line, sep); word; word = strtok(NULL,sep))
    {
        sum += isNumber(word);
    }
    printf("Результат: %d", sum);
}
```

Строка `sep` может быть уточнена, если будет уточнено, что такое **слово**. Заметим, что обязательно в составе `sep` должен быть `\n`.

Если нужны **только целые числа** - то `isNumber` делаем такой:

```
int isNumber(const char * word)
{
    char * end;
    long long d = strtoll(word,&end,0);
    return *end == 0;
}
```

Кстати, при этом будет найдено как число и, например, такое: `0XCAFE` :)

Comment: кстати а можно все это решить без указателей? так как не проходили их еще

Comment: Тогда надо разбирать, что такое число, вручную. И разделять строку на слова тоже вручную...